# Date value is not visible

Tags: html, css, reactjs, axios

I have make my own input component in react js.
and in input component i took input date, when i enter details in form all the values were stored in db but when i fetch data from
database on browser using axios in react js, data is not visible in date field. its shows dd/mm/yyyy

Input looks like this.

```
          <Box sx={{ flexBasis: 0, flexGrow: 1 }}>
            <Input
              autofill={state.startDate}
              id="startDate"
              value="Start Date"
              type="date"
              readOnly={disabled}
              required
            />
          </Box>
          <Box sx={{ flexBasis: 0, flexGrow: 1 }}>
            <Input
              autofill={state.endDate}
              id="endDate"
              value="End Date"
              readOnly={disabled}
              type="date"
            />
          </Box>
        </Box>


slice


export interface Data {
  culturalProgramId: number;
  referenceId: number;
  name: string;
  type: string;
  status: string;
  caseworker: string;
  startDate: string;
  endDate: string;
  totalCost: any;
  totalParticipation: any;
  sessionDetails: string;
  costOrParticipationDetails: string;
  outcomes: string;
  notes: string;
}

submit handler


const submitHandler = (e: FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const form: any = e.currentTarget;
    const formData: Data = {
      culturalProgramId: state.culturalProgramId,
      referenceId: state.referenceId,
      name: form.name.value,
      type: form.type.value,
      status: form.status.value,
      caseworker: form.caseworker.value,
      startDate: form.startDate.value,
      endDate: form.endDate.value,
      totalCost: form.totalCost.value,
      totalParticipation: form.totalParticipation.value,
      sessionDetails: form.sessionDetails.value,
      costOrParticipationDetails: form.costOrParticipationDetails.value,
      outcomes: form.outcomes.value,
      notes: form.notes.value,
    };


[output looks like this][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7Xai.jpg
```

Comment: I can see that your input is a component and not the native `input`. Which library are you using?

Comment: I am using Axios library.

Comment: Please reply and help if possible.

Comment: This probably doesn't solve the issue but you never open the first `<Box>`, but you do try to close it on row 20..

Comment: It was there with some extra fields in code.